# CUDA 9.1 - Missing recommended library

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, cuda

Here are my terminal output from installing CUDA 9.1:

```
Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
Installing the CUDA Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-9.1 ...
Missing recommended library: libGLU.so
Missing recommended library: libX11.so
Missing recommended library: libXi.so
Missing recommended library: libXmu.so

Installing the CUDA Samples in /home/username ...
Copying samples to /home/username/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.1_Samples now...
Finished copying samples.

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Installed
Toolkit:  Installed in /usr/local/cuda-9.1
Samples:  Installed in /home/username, but missing recommended libraries

Please make sure that
 -   PATH includes /usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin
 -   LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64, or, add  
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64 to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig as root

To uninstall the CUDA Toolkit, run the uninstall script in /usr/local
/cuda-9.1/bin
To uninstall the NVIDIA Driver, run nvidia-uninstall

Please see CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf in /usr/local/cuda-  
9.1/doc/pdf for detailed information on setting up CUDA.

Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_11273.log
```

Is it necessary to fix these `missing recommended libraries` and how can I make the `PATH` / `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inclusions to get CUDA run properly?

Answer (score 3):

run :

```
sudo apt-get install g++ freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev \
    libxmu-dev libxi-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
```

and you will be fine. read more [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#install-libraries)